# Is it possible to use Gutenberg on the front-end?

Tags: customization, block-editor

Now that WordPress 5 has the new [Gutenberg editor](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/), I'm interested in the possibility of using it programmatically on the front-end (for example as as a rich-text editor for bbPress).

In the past I've used [`wp_editor`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) but that still uses the old TinyMCE editor. I know there is [a demo site](https://frontenberg.tomjn.com/) using it on the front-end, but it doesn't go into how to actually save content.

Is it possible to programmatically use Gutenberg on the front-end or other places on the back-end? If not currently, is it on the roadmap?

Comment: You can see the source code for that demo here: https://github.com/tomjn/Frontenberg

Comment: @LiamStewart True, but it doesn't explain how to properly use the editor with the ability to save content safely (no XSS).

Comment: "Also, be careful, if you're logged in it will be fully functional, other users will see autosave notices and your changes will be saved!" It saves content if logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Gutenberg editor is now on frontend. Here is the solution.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontrom/

Comment: Sorry but what exactly of that plugin is in the front end?! Apart of being a 0.7 version plugin (and hence may and will change massively until a stable version 1 is released) I see nothing in the *front end* in that plugin. It uses the normal *back end* Gutenberg instance to edit templates, so what? Every kid can do that, this is not front end Gutenberg. Please correct me if I am wrong and point to the video or DOC that shows how things are using Gutenberg in the *front end* in that plugin. Thanks. Also, EVEN if it would, that plugin is not a SOLUTION. OP asked for code, this is a plugin.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Gutenberg Ramp](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg-ramp/) plugin. You selectively activate Gutenberg on certain pages and posts, giving you greater control.

Comment: And how is this - again, like above - front end? The question is:
**Is it possible to use Gutenberg on the front-end?**
Not "Can we use a plugin to load Gutenberg in backend instances"