# Use gutenberg block editor on plugin page (outside of a post)

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I'd like to use the block editor to manage content of the site-wide footer. With the classic editor, I simply need to register a plugin page and add a field that's just a `wp_editor` instance. I recall seeing something somewhere mentioning support for running Gutenberg outside the context of a post, but I can't track down the actual instructions, and skimming over `edit-form-blocks.php` doesn't make it clear what I need.

**Update:** My currently solution is to just use resusable blocks; I've exposed the manager to the admin menu, allowing users to create reusable blocks outside of a post. I then registered settings to allow assigning a reusable block to various template areas of the theme (like the Footer or, these days, the 404 Page content).

Comment: Relevant but no accepted answer: [Is it possible to use Gutenberg on the front-end?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323998/is-it-possible-to-use-gutenberg-on-the-front-end)

Comment: There's also experimental full site editing in 5.8 with theme support, e.g. in twentytwentyone, which is probably some way to what you want.

Comment: There's no way as of now to do it. I myself used TinyMCE 5 instead. It isn't as good, but has really good UI, compared to the old boring wp_editor. You should try that.